# Views Rewrite Results Shows "Delete Comment" shows as text to anonymous users

Tags: views, comments

I'm using a views to show my comments.
I've  Rewrite Results and add a delete comment field.

When users login they can click on the link
and delete the comment

But when a user is logout
any user can see [delete_comment] token

How do I hide the [delete_comment]token from anonymous users please?

Comment: what does it rewrite? is it the Delete Link Field? that field should obey permissions, so that if the user doesn't have permission to delete the content, the link doesn't show - but if you used a different method, you will have to include some php code or other functionality to perform a check manually I think

Answer (score 0):

set the permissions for anonymous users that they can't see or delete the comment.

Comment: Where are the "permissions for anonymous users that they can't see or delete the comment" please? Because it's not in the admin/people/permissions settings. Thanks for your help